# Problem with incorrect response of the minimize function of the scipy library in Python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

To calculate electrical circuits, I encountered the problem of an incorrect response from the minimize functions when calculating circuits with a parallel connection. For example this:

[image: parallel connections]

Creating a matrix of connections and fill in the resistance matrix:
Equation of the form: A*x = V ,where function sum(F * x**3) -> minimum

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

def CreateArrays(A,V):
    A = np.array(A) #matrix of connections
    V = np.array(V)
    buf = [0.1 for i in range(len(A[0]))]
    x0 = np.array(buf)
    return A,V,x0

def start(A,V,F):
    def obj_func(x):
        return np.sum(F * x**3)
    A,V,x0 = CreateArrays(A,V)
    lincon = LinearConstraint(A, lb=V, ub=V)
    
    res = minimize(obj_func, x0, method='trust-constr', constraints=lincon)
    return res.x
#Matrix of connections, vector V, vector F
I = start([[1, 0, 1], [0, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 0]], 
      [100, -100, 0],[1e-4, 1e-4, 8e-4])
print(I)
```

The result is [33.36666667 33.36666667 66.63333333] but it's a mistake; the true result is [66.63333333, 66.63333333, 33.36666667], where value of function is minimum.
The higher the resistance, the lower the electric currents.

I find minimum with this code:

```py
f = [1e-4,1e-4,8e-4]
s=0

save = 0.5
x = [0.5,0.5,99.5]
for i in range(len(x)):
    s = s + f[i] * x[i]**3
mini = s                     #start minimum
print(mini)
j = 0.5
while j < 100:
    x = [j, j, 100-j]  
    s=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        s = s + f[i] * x[i]**3 
    if s < mini:
        mini = s
        save = x  
    j =j +  0.5
print(mini,save)
```

Comment: What are your resistances? If the resistances are all equal then the current flowing through a single resistor from input to output should be twice the current flowing through a series of two resistors. In which case your "true" quantity would be wrong if it represented current. TBH, your problem description is vague in the extreme.

Comment: [1e-4,1e-4,8e-4] resistances. R1+R2 < R3

Comment: Please draw a better electric circuit. If the resistances are in the ratio 1:1:8 then, assuming an inflow current of 100 units, you will get current 80 units through O1 and O2 in your diagram (total voltage drop 80*(1+1) = 160 units) and current 20 units along the direct path (total voltage drop 20*8 = 160 units). Please explain what your are trying to do, as your answer doesn't reflect your diagram.

Comment: I want to find the currents at which the value of the obj_func function is the minimum.
The worst thing is that when the resistances change, nothing changes...

Comment: And in general, if I replace F with 0 (Zero) in the function, nothing will change at all, the answer is the same. That is, the minimize function cannot calculate such elementary schemes.
If the scheme is complicated, then it starts to work. But can you trust them if you can't even calculate simple ones?

Comment: Perhaps you had better explain what you are trying to minimise. I just used Kirchoff’s laws (by hand).

Comment: Electrical circuit power or water flow power, they are almost same:
P = Q**3 *F (water flow) or P = I**2 * R (elec).
I parse any scheme(any combination with bridges,parallel or serial connections,) to matrix to automate calculations. But when scheme is very simple like this - problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is here:

```
lincon = LinearConstraint(A, lb=V, ub=V)
```

This constraint seemed to mess up SLSQP, COBYLA, and trust-constr. SLSQP complains about singular constraint matrices. COBYLA complains that it only supports ineq constraints, not eq constraints. trust-constr works, but make no progress once it has found a solution that satisfies the constraints.

I found two things that helped.

The first was to use a better initial guess for x0, by starting with something that obeys the constraints.

```
def CreateArrays(A,V):
    A = np.array(A) #matrix of connections
    V = np.array(V)
    x0 = np.linalg.lstsq(A, V, rcond=None)[0]
    return A,V,x0
```

The second thing was to give the linear constraint some wiggle room, and allow it to be off in either direction by an epsilon. Initially, the linear constraint is allowed to vary by 0.001, and it is reduced from there.

```
def start(A,V,F):
    def obj_func(x):
        ret = np.sum(F * x**3)
        return ret
    A,V,x0 = CreateArrays(A,V)
    for eps in [1e-3, 1e-6, 1e-9, 0]:
        lincon = LinearConstraint(A, lb=V - eps, ub=V + eps)
        res = minimize(obj_func, x0, method='trust-constr', constraints=lincon)
        x0 = res.x
    return res.x
```

With these changes, trust-constr and COBYLA can both solve this.

Comment: Your option is good.
I solved the problem on my own in a different way:
Added two nodes with 3 parallel connections to the input matrices.